# DesiredCapabilities is obsolete in Selenium Web Driver V.3.14 How to write the code for Selenium grid in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have the following code. I update the selenium web driver to v3.14 and it shows the obsolete and error messages.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities; --deprecated

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome(); --has the error for Selennium wen driver v3.14

capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));

Uri uri = new Uri(hub url);

_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)); 


From class RemoteWebDriver in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote, it still has the ICapabilities parameter

public RemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout);
```

I saw some posts using Chrome options. But I still cannot make it work for selenium grid. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work without incident:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.PlatformName = "windows";

Uri uri = new Uri(hub url);

_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

Comment: Thanks JimEvans. It is working for me. Using the following code to get 'Windows' name. 

options.PlatformName = PlatformType.Windows.ToString();